# How to predict significant dominant regions of two sequence of numeric values by Hidden Markov Model?

Tags: r, regression, biostatistics, hidden-markov-model

I have few training on Hidden Markov Model. But, I intend to solve my problem by HMM. I would like to have your helps/directions to me.

Here, I have two variables to define the 8 one-dimension space (`coordinate.1`, `coordinate.2`). In this one-dimension space, there are two sequences of values (shared and specific). This means I would like to detect/guess/predict the regions (defined by two coordinates variables) which are significantly dominant (with higher values) by shared/specific in some consecutive cells (units of the `coordinate.2` in the dummy). I would like to get the coordinates (the 1st two variables) of such dominant regions for shared or specific.

I use R to construct a dummy (the real data are more complex than this

Here is my data set:

```
mydata <- data.frame(coordinate.1=rep(1:8, each=25), 
                     coordinate.2=rep(seq(100, 2500, 100), 8), 
                     shared=rep(c(100,30,100), c(5,15,5)), 
                     specific=rep(c(25,90,20,30), c(5,7,8,5)))
```

Here is how I happen to make a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

pdf("shared_specific.pdf", width = 14, height = 8)
p.test<-ggplot(mydata, aes(coordinate.2)) + 
       geom_line(aes(y = shared, colour = "shared")) +
       geom_line(aes(y = specific, colour = "specific")) +
       facet_grid(coordinate.1 ~., scales = "free_x") +
       scale_x_continuous("coordinate.2") + 
       scale_y_continuous("shared and specific")
p.test
dev.off()
```